# Как доработать калькулятор с выпадающим списком?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, json

Нужна помощь, так как новичок в программировании. Хочу сделать подобный калькулятор с выпадающим списком: https://u037247.stepform.io/CIJV9RM, но там нет кода. Так же, при условии, если итог равен 0, то выводить значение: "Нет данных". С css все более грустно). Буду очень благодарен Вам за помощь.
Мои наработки:

```js
function calcAndShow() {
  let val = $("select.control").val();
  let num = parseInt($("input.control").val() || 0);
  let sum = val * num;
  if (!isNaN(sum) && sum > 0) {
    $(".text.big").removeClass("zero");
    let res = $(".text.big").text().replace(/\D+/g, "");
    res = parseInt(res);
    if (isNaN(res)) res = 0;
    let dif = Math.abs(sum - res);
    $(".text.big").text(sum).each(function() {
      $(this).prop("Counter", res).animate({
          Counter: parseInt($(this).text())
        }, {
          duration: 400,
          easing: "linear",
          step: function(now) { $(this).text(Math.ceil(now).toLocaleString("ru")); }
        });
    });
  } else { $(".text.big").addClass("zero").text(""); }
}
$("#maincalcs").on("input", calcAndShow).trigger("input");
```

```css
   

 @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&display=swap");
    
    body { background-color: #eceff1; }
    
    #maincalcs {
      margin: auto;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      max-width: 820px;
      font: 400 16px/1em Montserrat, Arial, sans-serif;
      background-color: #fff;
    }
    
    .values, .numbers {
      margin: auto;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      gap: 1em;
      max-width: 820px;
      padding: 1.25em 1.5em 1.5em;
      background-color: #fff;
    }
    
    b { font-size: 1.15em; color: #37474f; }
    b::after { content: " *"; color: #f00; }
    
    .control {
      border-radius: 0.4em;
      border: 2px solid #eceff1;
      font: inherit;
      color: #37474f;
      background-color: #eceff1;
    }
    select.control { padding: 0.5em 2em 0.5em 0.6em; }
    select.control option { background: #fff; color: #37474f; }
    input.control { padding: 0.5em 0.6em; }
    
    .result {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      gap: 1em;
      padding: 1.5em;
      color: #fff;
      background-color: #2196f3;
    }
    
    .big { font-weight: 300; font-size: 2.25em; }
    .big::after { content: ' руб.'; }
    .big.zero::after { content: 'Нет данных'; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="maincalcs">
  <div class="controls">
    <div class="values">
      <b>Выберите значение:</b>
      <select class="control" onmousedown="if(this.options.length>5){this.size=5;}"  onchange='this.size=0;' onblur="this.size=0;">
        <option disabled selected>Выберите пункт...</option>
        <option value="10">1 (10)</option>
        <option value="255">2 (255)</option>
        <option value="3704">3 (3704)</option>
        <option value="0">4 (0)</option>
        <option value="0">4 (0)</option>
        <option value="0">4 (0)</option>
        <option value="0">4 (0)</option>
        <option value="0">4 (0)</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="numbers">
      <b>Укажите количество:</b>
      <input class="control" type="number" min="0" step="1">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="result">
    <div class="text">Итого</div>
    <div class="text big zero"></div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Если Вы новичок, то начните с копирования кода без ошибок.

Comment: @UModeL, извините, пожалуйста, просто Ваш код был максимально близок к примеру...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> С css все более грустно).

Не грустите...

```js
function calcAndShow() {
  let val = $("select.control").val();
  let num = parseInt($("input.control").val() || 0);
  let sum = val * num;
  if (!isNaN(sum) && sum > 0) {
    $(".text.big").removeClass("zero");
    let res = $(".text.big").text().replace(/\D+/g, "");
    res = parseInt(res);
    if (isNaN(res)) res = 0;
    let dif = Math.abs(sum - res);
    $(".text.big").text(sum).each(function() {
      $(this).prop("Counter", res).animate({
          Counter: parseInt($(this).text())
        }, {
          duration: 400,
          easing: "linear",
          step: function(now) { $(this).text(Math.ceil(now).toLocaleString("ru")); }
        });
    });
  } else { $(".text.big").addClass("zero").text(""); }
}
$("#maincalcs").on("input", calcAndShow).trigger("input");
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&display=swap");

body { background-color: #eceff1; }

#maincalcs {
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 820px;
  font: 400 16px/1em Montserrat, Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.values, .numbers {
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 1em;
  max-width: 820px;
  padding: 1.25em 1.5em 1.5em;
  background-color: #fff;
}

b { font-size: 1.15em; color: #37474f; }
b::after { content: " *"; color: #f00; }

.control {
  border-radius: 0.4em;
  border: 2px solid #eceff1;
  font: inherit;
  color: #37474f;
  background-color: #eceff1;
}
select.control { padding: 0.5em 2em 0.5em 0.6em; }
select.control option { background: #fff; color: #37474f; }
input.control { padding: 0.5em 0.6em; }

.result {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1em;
  padding: 1.5em;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #2196f3;
}

.big { font-weight: 300; font-size: 2.25em; }
.big::after { content: ' руб.'; }
.big.zero::after { content: 'Нет данных'; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="maincalcs">
  <div class="controls">
    <div class="values">
      <b>Выберите значение:</b>
      <select class="control">
        <option disabled selected>Выберите пункт...</option>
        <option value="10">1 (10)</option>
        <option value="255">2 (255)</option>
        <option value="3704">3 (3704)</option>
        <option value="0">4 (0)</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="numbers">
      <b>Укажите количество:</b>
      <input class="control" type="number" min="0" step="1">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="result">
    <div class="text">Итого</div>
    <div class="text big zero"></div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Извините, что снова беспокою.. Я добавил полоску прокрутки в выпадающий список и калькулятор перестал работать. Можете, подсказать, пожалуйста, как исправить js и css? Код я заменил в коде вопроса

Comment: Работу калькулятора починил с помощью удаления лишнего js и добавлением данного кода, но с css беда): `<select class="control" onmousedown="if(this.options.length>8){this.size=8;}" onchange='this.size=0;' onblur="this.size=0;">`